# send form data from child component to parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I created a parent component CommentBox.js and a child component CommentForm.js

```
#CommentForm.js
....
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
content: '',
});
const { content } = formData;

const onChange = (e) =>{
   setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }); 
}
.....

#CommentBox.js
...................
< CommentForm onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}/>
.......................
```

I want to get the "content" data in CommentBox.js .

How can I get that formdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data flows from top to bottom in *React*. In order to accomplish what you want, you would have to give the parent component a new state and pass the update function down to the child component:

```
// CommentBox.js
// New state variable to save the data
const [ data, setData ] = useState({});

<CommentForm onSubmit={onSubmitHandler} setData={setData} />

// CommentForm.js
const onChange = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const name = e.target.name;
   const value = e.target.value;

   setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
   // Updates the state of the parent component
   props.setData(data => ({ ...data, [name]: value })); 
}
```

Now the child component updates both his state as well as the state of the parent component.

**EDIT**
There can be some errors reusing events, so I updated the above answer.

Comment: I am getting bunch of errors  like TypeError: e.target is null  when I try to type in text area.

Comment: No I was able to write and submit the form.

Comment: There can be problems when reusing events. I updated my answer.